# Call function when Google Maps + other library are fully loaded?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-maps

I load the google map api and execute the init function `initMap()` with the `callback` parameter :

```
<script async="" defer="" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=xxxxxxxxxxx&amp;callback=initMap"></script>
```

I want to use an other script (`js-rich-marker`) in order to create  a custom marker (with css style).

I load :

```
script async="" defer="" src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/googlemaps/js-rich-marker/gh-pages/src/richmarker-compiled.js"></script>
```

But `initMap();` doesn’t work on page load :

```
ReferenceError: Can't find variable: RichMarker
```

(I know the script can work because i can update the map with a menu which update the map with AJAX and in this case it's working.).

I guess it is because the init function is executed before `js-rich-marker` is fully loaded.

I’ve tried to call the init function when everything is loaded but it is still not ok.

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event){
  initMap();
});

$(window).load(function() {
   initMap();
});

$(window).bind("load", function() {
   // code goes here
});
```

How can i call a function one everything is loaded ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
window.document.onload= function(e){

}
window.onload = function(e){

}
```

and call next js-rich-marker
example:

Comment: `window.onload` is the solution`. More info here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588040/window-onload-vs-document-onload